# Transpose multiples rows into columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe:

| ID1 | ID2 | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | OCC |
| A | 01 | HUI |
| A | 01 | IAC |
| A | 03 | OCC |
| B | 05 | OCC |
| B | 05 | HUI |
| C | 08 | IAC |

I would want the category to be transposed into max amount of Category values a group can have columns and fill in to those columns. The group is ID1 and ID2

| ID1 | ID2 | Category1 | Category2 | Category3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | OCC | HUI | IAC |
| A | 03 | OCC |  |  |
| B | 05 | OCC | IAC |  |
| C | 08 | IAC |  |  |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assign row numbers per ID1 and ID2 then prefix the row number with 'Category'. Then, pivot the dataframe on the combination of ID1, ID2, and col

```
W = Window.partitionBy('ID1', 'ID2').orderBy('Category')
df1 = (
    df
    .withColumn('col', F.row_number().over(W))
    .withColumn('col', F.concat(F.lit('Category'), 'col'))
    .groupby('ID1', 'ID2')
    .pivot('col')
    .agg(F.first('Category'))
)
```

---

```
df1.show()
+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
|ID1|ID2|Category1|Category2|Category3|
+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
|  A|  1|      HUI|      IAC|      OCC|
|  A|  3|      OCC|     null|     null|
|  B|  5|      HUI|      OCC|     null|
|  C|  8|      IAC|     null|     null|
+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
```